# how to tell what version of windows and/or cmd.exe a batch file is running on?

Tags: windows, cmd

How can one determine what version of Windows and/or cmd.exe a batch file is running on?

There is no `cmd /version` that I've been able to find and the results of SET in a command prompt session don't give anything obviously unique (between XP and Win7 anyway).

Comment: batch file from MS for [How to determine the OS type in a logon script](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=190899), only covers W95,NT,2000, Enterprise NT.

Comment: this script from SS64 works from W9x thru XP, but *not* XPx64 or Win7 x64 - http://ss64.com/nt/ver.html

Comment: reg.exe snippet to retrieve version #:
{{{ reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v CurrentVersion }}}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of `cmd.exe` *should* actually be pretty irrelevant, unless you try to use features that didn't exist before (in `command.com` for example). There is the pseudovariable

```
%cmdextversion%
```

which holds the version of the command extensions which has been 2 for ages (at least back to NT 4, iirc).

But, back to the point: Running `ver` and parsing the version string might be your best bet:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%x in ('ver') do set WINVER=%%x
set WINVER=%WINVER:Version =%
```

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction and giving me a push start. It was a great help!

Answer (score 16):

you can use the "systeminfo" @ cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\Tagon8>systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 8 Release Preview
OS Version:                6.2.8400 N/A Build 8400
```

Comment: The output is localized, so in non-English Windows versions, there  will be no "OS Name"  or   "OS Version"

Answer (score 9):

> I found a shorter way using ver as well:

Could be even shorter:

```
ver | find "5.1" >nul && goto ver_winxp
```

Comment: Thanks! Would have been better to add this as a comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11102816/14420 than make a new post.

Answer (score 4):

Type "ver" at a command prompt.

Next time around, since this isn't really programming related but server or user related, you might try serverfault.com or superuser.com.

Comment: I thought of that but there is a much bigger collection of batch file Q&A here than on either of those sites. Scripts are not quite programming and yet can't be said to be exactly not-programming either. In any case, thanks for the answer. I knew it had be something simple.

Comment: I wouldn't say that batch questions immediately have to go to SF or SU. They belong here quite well.

Comment: Johannes; if something's tagged "cmd" and "Windows", I can't help but thing SF or SU.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

I found a shorter way using `ver` as well:

```
...
ver | find "5.1"
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_winxp
...
```

This will find XP, replace the string with your wanted versions

Answer (score 2):

To find the windows version using `WMIC` you can use:

```
wmic os get version
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will need the following to determine the SKU (Win7).
I'm using some of this script to pick the right OS and XML during sysprep.
Hope it helps!

```
@echo off

set ver=Unknown

systeminfo > C:\sysinfo

findstr /e /c:"Enterprise " C:\sysinfo 1>nul 2>nul    
if %errorlevel% equ 0 set ver=Enterprise

findstr /e /c:"Ultimate " C:\sysinfo 1>nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 set ver=Ultimate

findstr /e /c:"Professional " C:\sysinfo 1>nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 set ver=Professional

findstr /e /c:"Home Premium " C:\sysinfo 1>nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 set ver=Home Premium

findstr /e /c:"Home Basic " C:\sysinfo 1>nul 2>nul
if %errorlevel% equ 0 set ver=Home Basic    

del /f /q C:\SP\sysinfo 1>nul 2>nul
Echo Windows 7 %ver%

pause    
exit
```

Comment: Thanks for a usable script, though I'm leary of dumping anything to the root of C: and would use `%temp%\sysinfo` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The internal command `ver` reports windows version number (which could have been learned by typing `help` at the command prompt).

There is a [dynamic variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) `%CMDEXTVERSION%`, but it hasn't progressed in several releases so it's only useful for delineating [between Windows NT and Windows 2000 and newer](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntif.php). (Thanks @Joey, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792881/14420).)

Here's a batch to parse the output of ver for XP and newer, courtesy of [Simon Sheppard](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=3155#p3155):

```
@echo off
Setlocal
:: Get windows Version numbers
For /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%G in ('ver') Do (set _version=%%G) 

For /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=. " %%G in ('echo %_version%') Do (set _major=%%G& set _minor=%%H& set _build=%%I) 

Echo Major version: %_major%  Minor Version: %_minor%.%_build%

if "%_major%"=="5" goto sub5
if "%_major%"=="6" goto sub6

Echo unsupported version
goto:eof

:sub5
::Winxp or 2003
if "%_minor%"=="2" goto sub_2003
Echo Windows XP [%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%]
goto:eof

:sub_2003
Echo Windows 2003 or xp 64 bit [%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%]
goto:eof

:sub6
if "%_minor%"=="1" goto sub7
Echo Windows Vista or Windows 2008 [%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%]
goto:eof

:sub7
Echo Windows 7 or Windows 2008 R2 [%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%]
goto:eof
```

And here's my own fairly complete, largely academic, kick at the can which returns the parsed version number as environment variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: from http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=3136#p3136
::==================================
::variables
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86   set pro_arch=32 Bit (x86)
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64 set pro_arch=64 Bit (AMD64)
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==IA64 set pro_arch=Itanium 64 Bit (IA64)

:Main
    call :clean
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%x in ('ver') do set cmdver=%%x
    set cmdver=%cmdver:Version =%
    call :parse_cmdver
    call :ver%cmdver%
    call :Report
    goto :End


:clean
    :: Ensure we don't inherit values from previous runs
    set _verCmd=
    set _verMajor=
    set _verMinor=
    set _verBuild=
    set _verWin=
    goto :eof

:Parse_cmdver
    :: Turn "5.1.2306" string into actionable variables
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=." %%g in ("%cmdver%") do (
        set major=%%g
        set minor=%%h
        set build=%%i
        )
    goto :eof

:Report
    echo.
    echo.   CMD version is %cmdver%
    echo.   which probably means %longver% %pro_arch%
    echo.
    goto :eof

:Report2
    echo.   The numbers are stored in the following variables:
    echo.
    set _ver
    goto :eof


::Table of version numbers built from 
:: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows#Timeline_of_releases
:ver1.01
    set longver=Windows 1.01
    set shortver=Win101
    goto :eof

:ver2.03
    set longver=Windows 2.03
    set shortver=Win203
    goto :eof

:ver2.10
    set longver=Windows 2.10
    set shortver=Win21
    goto :eof

:ver2.11
    set longver=Windows 2.11
    set shortver=Win211
    goto :eof

:ver3.0
    set longver=Windows 3.0
    set shortver=Win3
    goto :eof

:ver3.1
    set longver=Windows 3.1, Windows For Workgroups 3.1, or Windows NT 3.1
    set shortver=Win31/WFW31/WinNT31
    goto :eof

:ver3.11
    set longver=Windows For Workgroups 3.11
    set shortver=WFW311
    goto :eof

:ver3.2
    set longver=Windows 3.2 (released in Simplified Chinese only)
    set shortver=Win32ch
    goto :eof

:ver3.5
    set longver=Windows NT 3.5
    set shortver=WinNT35
    goto :eof

:ver3.51
    set longver=Windows NT 3.51
    set shortver=WinNT351
    goto :eof

:ver4.0.950
    set longver=Windows 95
    set shortver=Win95
    goto :eof

:ver4.0.1381
    set longver=Windows NT 4.0
    set shortver=WinNT4
    goto :eof

:ver4.90.3000
    set longver=Windows Me
    set shortver=WinMe
    goto :eof

:ver4.10.1998
    set longver=Windows 98
    set shortver=Win98
    goto :eof

:ver4.10.2222
    set longver=Windows 98 SE
    set shortver=Win98SE
    goto :eof

:ver5.0.2195
    set longver=Windows 2000
    set shortver=Win2K
    goto :eof

:ver5.1.2600
    set longver=Windows XP or Windows Fundamentals for Legacy PCs
    set shortver=WinXP/WinFun
    goto :eof

:ver5.2.3790
    set longver=Windows XP, Windows XP Pro or Windows Server 2003
    set shortver=WinXP/WinXP-Pro/Server2003
    goto :eof

:ver5.2.4500
    set longver=Windows Home Server
    set shortver=WinHomeServer
    goto :eof

:ver6.0.6002
    set longver=Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008
    set shortver=Vista/Server2008
    goto :eof

:ver6.1.7600
    set longver=Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2
    set shortver=Win7/Server2008R2
    goto :eof


:End
:: return version to calling shell/script,
:: see http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html
endlocal & set _verCmd=%cmdver% & set _verMajor=%major% & set _verMinor=%minor% & set _verBuild=%build% & set _verWin=%shortver%
call :Report2 :: comment this line out to suppress extra reporting
```