# Vimscript: How can I get the Operating System version?

Tags: vim

Even though it's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783224/is-there-a-command-in-vimscript-to-get-the-current-operating-system) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146633/vimscript-how-do-i-get-the-os-that-is-running-vim) question I need to know the current version of the operating system while vim is running.  The previous questions don't help me since they describe a feature set of the executable; what I need is a function to return the os version either name or number (e.g. as listed in this [widows version chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Is there one?

Comment: It would be interesting to share _why_ you absolutely need the Windows version inside Vim. As Vim is very portable, the need for this usually is a bad smell.

Comment: @IngoKarkat:  Why does this have a bad smell?  You provided a good example in your answer below - any vim script invoking an external application via `system` could do a version check for a specific feature.  So why not extend this concept to check the version of the operating system?  It's because that vim is so portable and *extendable with vimscript* that I would argue that this is a valid question.

Comment: There's no need for a version check with `system()`. If the executable exists (which can also be checked via `executable()`, it should work, or at least return an exit status !=0 when the environment is unsupported; no need for a version check. Why don't you tell us your use case? PS: I didn't downvote the question.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: I believe that there is a version check needed in some specialized cases when `system('foo')` performs differently based on the version of foo.  As an example, please consider `cmd.exe` from this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792740/how-to-tell-what-version-of-windows-and-or-cmd-exe-a-batch-file-is-running-on).  While `executable('cmd.exe')` would return true it would not mean that cmd.exe is the same version and system('cmd.exe`) is not guaranteed to perform the same way.  So within vimscript, I would need an os version number to handle all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Windows but on Mac OS X you can do:

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion
```

and on Ubuntu you can do:

```
$ lsb_release -rs
```

This quick hack seems to work, you'll have to adapt it to your needs:

```
function! GetSysVersion()
  let os=substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')
  if os == 'Darwin' || os == 'Mac'
    let sys_version=substitute(system('sw_vers -productVersion'), '\n', '', '')
  elseif os == 'Linux'
    let sys_version=substitute(system('lsb_release -rs'), '\n', '', '')
  endif
  echo sys_version
endfunction
```

Comment: This confirms the solution that I had in my head :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(Just to make 30 characters)

`echo exec('cat "/etc/issue"')`

Comment: You're assuming the user/admin didn't change that file.  I do.  Quite useful for login identification both locally (/etc/issue) and remotely (/etc/issue.net) (see sshd_config banner)

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the Win32 function `GetVersionEx()`, you have to write a DLL that exposes the function, and invoke it from Vim via `libcall()`. For all the implementation details, see

```
:help libcall()
```

Alternatively, you could write an executable and use `system()` to parse its output.

Comment: Compiling a separate exe or dll seems a bit overkill when `system('ver')` would be enough in a windows environment.

Comment: You asked about `GetVersionEx()`. If `ver` information (and parsing it) is fine, use `system()`, but all means.